# Как вывести список объектов карты при использовании LoadingObjectManager?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Для подгрузки элементов на карту использую **LoadingObjectManager**.

```
var myMap = new ymaps.Map("pickup-map", {
    center: [61.9363, 99.4921],
    zoom: 9,
    controls: ['zoomControl', 'searchControl', 'fullscreenControl']
});

var loadingObjectManager  = new ymaps.LoadingObjectManager('/my-link/?%b',
    {
       paddingTemplate: 'callbackFunction_%b',
       clusterize: true,
    }
);

myMap.geoObjects.add(loadingObjectManager);
```

LoadingObjectManager отправляет запрос на бэк и получает ответ в виде jsonp с информацией об объектах, попадающими в зону видимости. На карте метки отображаются и кластеризуются корректно.

Ответ от сервера выглядит примерно так:

```
callback_function({
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 0,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [55.831903, 37.411961]
      },
      "properties": {
        "balloonContent": "Содержимое балуна",
        "clusterCaption": "Метка 1",
        "hintContent": "Текст подсказки"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 1,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [55.763338, 37.565466]
      },
      "properties": {
        "balloonContent": "Содержимое балуна",
        "clusterCaption": "Метка 2",
        "hintContent": "Текст подсказки"
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Но сбоку от карты необходимо создать список объектов и, естественно, обновлять его содержимое.
Аналогичная история реализована на wildberries при выборе пункта выдачи: слева список пунктов, находящихся в зоне видимости, справа - карта с метками.
[image: Скрин ВБ]

**Как получить массив объектов на карте?** Вся информация, необходимая для создания списка, находится в properties у каждого объекта. Но при использовании LoadingObjectManager коллекция объектов не проходит через сохранение в какую-либо переменнную.

**За что зацепиться для обновления списка?** Обновление при добавлении object не поможет - при небольшом зуме данные влетают кластерами и не триггерят добавление объектов.

Если получить эту информацию с LoadingObjectManager невозможно, тогда с помощью чего решить данную задачу?

**Solved.**

```
myMap.events.add('boundschange', function () {
            ymaps
              .geoQuery(loadingObjectManager.objects)
              .searchInside(myMap)
              .each(function (object) {
                console.log(object.properties.get('name'));
              });
          });
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: а в `mgr.objects` пусто что ли?

Comment: @teran Что есть mgr.objects? 
Попытки достучаться до коллекции LoadingObjectManager к успеху не привели, даже через .objects. Плюс - абсолютно непонятно на что повесить слушатель обновления, дабы перечитывать данные и обновлять список.

Comment: https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/loading-object-manager/frontend.html тут вроде написано, что должны быть в `.objects`

Comment: там кстати если будут, то наверное не только видимые на карте, но и во всем тайле. так что отфильтровать по попадающим в зону еще придется. то есть фактически обновлять надо по событиям движения и масштабирования карты. хотя, мб все и не так.

Comment: @teran Действительно, в loadingObjectManager.objects лежат объекты, входящие в тайл. Отсортировала с помощью searchInside для определения фактически видимых. 

Благодарю!)